# How to make DIVs flow to the left in a x-scrollable pane with CSS?

Tags: css, css-float, overflow, html

I want to create a x-scrollable panel of specific height and width where DIVs should be positioned in a row to the left insted of to the bottom (see this example: http://jsbin.com/ohahac/1/edit). I want to make this panel scrollable to the left only.

what am I missing or doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML+RDFa 1.1//EN">

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>untitled</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="TextMate http://macromates.com/">
        <meta name="author" content="headkit-studio">
        <!-- Date: 2013-03-21 -->
        <style>
            *{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            .blockdiv{
                height: 500px;
                float:left;
                min-height:400px;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main" style="overflow:hidden;">
            <div class="leftbar" style="width:150px; height: 500px; position: relative; float: left; display: inline; background-color:black;">LEFT</div>
            <div id="content" style="width:100%">
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="region" style="overflow-x:scroll; width:1200px; border:1px dotted black; height: 500px;">
                        <div id="01" class="blockdiv" style="background-color:yellow; width:450px">1</div>
                        <div id="01" class="blockdiv" style="background-color:blue; width:690px">2</div>
                        <div id="01" class="blockdiv" style="background-color:silver; width:500px">3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

thnx!!

EDIT: works fine with white-space:nowrap; (have a look:http://jsbin.com/ohahac) but this solution adds some gaps between the div-elements! also the vertical scrollbar is a no-go. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want `inline-block` only. not with `float:left`
also `white-space:nowrap;` for the region wrapper.

http://jsbin.com/ohahac/15/edit

here is a simpler one

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/JuEVy/

Comment: hey, thanx! I will try that. yes, simpler is better but I needed to simulate my actual site layout here.

Comment: @headkit its an interesting layout.

Comment: thanx you. but also relatively complicated. you solution is cool but creates a little gap between the rowed div-elements and adds a little hight to the panel because of the scrollbar.

Comment: I edited the code, please have a look here: http://jsbin.com/ohahac
unfort. there are these gaps between the DIVs and an y-scrollbar appears, too. :-(

Comment: isn't that cheating? ;-) and what about the ugly vertical scrollbar?

Comment: not so many options http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @headkit if you dont want the margin in first element you can remove it. see this updated http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/JuEVy/

Comment: o.k. - I used the negative margin hack. the vertical scrollbar disappeard when I added the height to the #main-div with the overflow:hidden;. works fine now. thank you for your help!